# Android Java Application Communication With .Net Web Service

Tags: android, .net, web-services, soap, communication

I am new to stackoverflow, but I always find the answers I need on it from other people's questions. This time, I had no such luck.

I have am developping an android application that communicates with a .NET web service. The code seems fine, however I am sure something is wrong because the result isn't what I need.

I have a login method in the web service which is below.

```
[WebMethod]
    public String login(String username, String password)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        DataSet dataset = null;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = null; ;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=Senior; Trusted_Connection=True");
            dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
            adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Employee";
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "employees");
                String user, pass;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables["employees"].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    user = dataset.Tables["employees"].Rows[i]["Username"].ToString();
                    pass = dataset.Tables["employees"].Rows[i]["Password"].ToString();
                    if (user == username && pass == password)
                        return "Login Successful";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            adapter.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            return "Login Failed"
    }
```

I also have a class that allows soap communication with my web service.

After calling this method, a method called result in my android project is called to parse the result. Here's it's code:

```
void result()
{
    if (echosoap.myResult != null)
    {
        String answer = echosoap.myResult.toString();
        et1.setText(answer);
        if(answer=="Login Successful")
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultWindow.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this method always sets et1 (An EditText component) to "Login Failed".

I have tested my code in a regular (non-web service) application and the result was fine.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: In Java, you should not compare `String` using `==`. `String` is an object and `==` tests whether 2 objects are the same object. Because of string interning, this may, or may not be true. Instead, use the equals method to test the contents. `if(answer.equals("Login Successful")`.  This does not resolve your problem though.  Several observations.  In your C# method, you should use `using` and a paramterised query.  Your SQL should be something like `SELECT * FROM emplyeees WHERE username = @username AND password = @password".  Then just test whether the result set `hasRows`.

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out IIS changes the default login credentials when using trusted connection.
The solution was:
1- Open IIS
2- Expand the connection from the list on the left
3- Click on "Application Pools"
4- Click on "DefaultAppPool"
5- Click on "Advanced Settings..." from the actions on the right
6- Scroll down to "Process Model"
7- Open "Identity"
8- Choose "Custom account:"
9- Click on "Set"
10-In the "User name" field add (YourComputerName)\(YourCurrentUsername) and in the "Password" field add your user's password.